# App store rejecting app because of UIWebView, but UIWebView only in comments, not actual code

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

I'm getting an app rejected because if contains UIWebView.  When I rune

`grep -r "UIWebView" .` I get back the following results:

```
Binary file ./App.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/codegama.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
./Pods/AppAuth/README.md:for the auth request. `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are explicitly *not*
Binary file ./Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a matches
./Pods/GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser,
```

So I tried opening the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file with a text editor, but it's a different file format.  The other reference in the paypal Pod is just something in the ReadMe file.

So my question is, can I just remove the word from the paypal readme file?
And second, how do I edit the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate to remove that reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libPayPalMobile.a` inside of the [PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) most likely contains a reference to UIWebView in it.

However, the PayPal SDK is deprecated and it is now recommended to use [Braintree Direct](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/). So to solve this issue, you must either remove your integration with the PayPal SDK or migrate to use Braintree Direct.